# How can i multiprocess my pyrogram bot to work each commands parallely

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Basically I made a pyrogram bot which has 2 commands . First Commands do some work that takes 30 sec to finish and second command takes only 5 sec to finish.

So my problem is , when a user gives First Command which is /TASK1 , and at the same time another user gives Second Command which is /TASK2 , then second commands works very slow and it takes 10-15 sec to complete where it is genarally takes second commands 5 sec to execute.

So now i wanted to work both of my commands separately or parallelly so that they can excute as a totally different one from another and do not interfare one to another.

So basically how can i do that? how can i run these two commands separately or works like two different processes?

Please Everyone Help Me ...

````
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client, compose,filters
from defs import *
async def main():
    #
    user = Client(user_detail)
    bot = Client(bot_detail)
    clients = [
        user ,
        bot
    ]
    #FIRST COMMAND TASK1 TAKE 30 SEC TO FINISH
    @bot.on_message(filters.command("TASK1", [".","/"]))
    async def cmd_TASK1(client,message):
        #DOING FIRST STEP
        first_def()
        first_step = await message.reply_text("First Step Done .",message.id)
        #DOING SECOND STEP
        second_def()
        second_step = await bot.edit_message_text(message.chat.id,first_step.id,"Second Step Done.")
        #DOIND THIRD STEP
        third_def()
        third_step = await bot.edit_message_text(message.chat.id,second_step.id,"Third Step Done.")
        #DONE EVERYTHING
        await bot.edit_message_text(message.chat.id,third_step.id,"All Step Done.")
  
    #SECOND COMMAND TASK2 TAKE 5 SEC TO FINISH
    @bot.on_message(filters.command("TASK2", [".","/"]))
    async def cmd_TASK2(client,message):
        #DOING FIRST STEP
        task2_def1()
        first_step = await message.reply_text("50% Done.",message.id)
        #DOING SECOND STEP
        task2_def2()
        await bot.edit_message_text(message.chat.id,first_step.id,"All Done Successfully")
      
    await compose(clients)
asyncio.run(main())
```
`
````

Comment: It depends whether the *"steps"* are fully independent, for example, you can't normally go left and right at the same time. And also whether you have sufficient resources to do both at once.

Comment: it depends on what your functions do, the answer will involve using [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), with `loop.run_in_executor` , but there are many restrictions, such as you cannot use or update global variables and you cannot share sockets, and if you are holding any resources then they should be acquired and released, overall if you cannot do it while knowing what your functions do then we cannot help you while not knowing what your functions do.

Answer (score 0):

your functions look like they are modifying the global scope (because they have no arguments or return), so they cannot really be multiprocessed without major modifications,

a very naive method is to use `loop.run_in_executor` which by default will run the task in another thread, so you won't block the eventloop, but your code won't get "faster", it will have the same throughput due to the GIL, but the smaller task will have less wait time as it will be interleaved with the long task.

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    #
    user = Client(user_detail)
    bot = Client(bot_detail)
    clients = [
        user,
        bot
    ]

    # FIRST COMMAND TASK1 TAKE 30 SEC TO FINISH
    @bot.on_message(filters.command("TASK1", [".", "/"]))
    async def cmd_TASK1(client, message):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        # DOING FIRST STEP
        await loop.run_in_executor(func=first_def)
        first_step = await message.reply_text("First Step Done .", message.id)
        # DOING SECOND STEP
        await loop.run_in_executor(func=second_def)
        second_step = await bot.edit_message_text(message.chat.id, first_step.id, "Second Step Done.")
        # DOIND THIRD STEP
        await loop.run_in_executor(func=third_def)
        third_step = await bot.edit_message_text(message.chat.id, second_step.id, "Third Step Done.")
        # DONE EVERYTHING
        await bot.edit_message_text(message.chat.id, third_step.id, "All Step Done.")

    # SECOND COMMAND TASK2 TAKE 5 SEC TO FINISH
    @bot.on_message(filters.command("TASK2", [".", "/"]))
    async def cmd_TASK2(client, message):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        # DOING FIRST STEP
        await loop.run_in_executor(func=task2_def1)
        first_step = await message.reply_text("50% Done.", message.id)
        # DOING SECOND STEP
        await loop.run_in_executor(func=task2_def2)
        await bot.edit_message_text(message.chat.id, first_step.id, "All Done Successfully")

    await compose(clients)
```

again, if any part of your code is not "threadsafe" (such as using sockets) then you are inviting a lot of problems and will have to add synchronization primatives around the critical parts of your code to ensure it will work as expected.

generally a function with no arguments or return look like it is modifying the global scope, which will invite race conditions, so it's better to write your application in the form of functions that take arguments and produce a return with almost no side-effects on any global scope.

using another process instead of thread is done by filling the first argument of `loop.run_in_executor` with an instance of [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor), but your code has to get around the many problems of IPC.